# how to make dynamic size for the uicollection view cell in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, autolayout

I am using uicollection view to display the images in grid view format.I am able to display the cells but the height & width is not increased for iPad it only display as the small blocks.Please tell me how can i make it dynamic.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have used following code for make it dynamic.

## pragma mark Collection view layout things

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    if (collectionView==self.album_collection_view) {
        return 2.0;
    }
    else
        return 2.0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    if (collectionView==self.album_collection_view) {
        return 2.0;
    }
    else
        return 2.0;
}
// Layout: Set Edges
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    // return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,8,0,8);  // top, left, bottom, right
    if (collectionView==self.album_collection_view) {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5,0,0,0);
    }// top, left, bottom, right
    else
        return  UIEdgeInsetsMake(5,0,0,0);
    
}
```

Please tell me how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution

```
 -(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

YourCollectionCell * cell = (YourCollectionCell *) [YourCollectionViewObj cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell == nil) {

            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourCollectionCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 20);
            // SET YOUR CONTENT
            [cell layoutIfNeeded];

        }

        CGSize CellSize = [cell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize withHorizontalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh verticalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow];


        return CellSize;}
```

In case above solution not meet your needs,To obtain what you want, you should create your own UICollectionViewLayout (or maybe UICollectionViewFlowLayout) subclass, where you perform all the computations needed for placing every item in the right frame.

Take a look here for a [great tutorial](https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/collection-view-layouts/) and here for [something similar to what you want](https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout).

Comment: What is YourCollectionViewObj here?

Comment: @deepakkumar its the object of your collection view

Comment: I have not made any separte nib for my collection view container

Comment: so you can check the below links that i provided

Comment: i need a quick solution.

Comment: then you can use RFQuiltLayout its the best and easy to embed in code

Answer (score -1):

If you want to increase cell height and width you have to use `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method. for that you have to add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` delegate.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}
```

Comment: will it make dynmaic size for all devices.

Comment: if you want to show 4 cell in each row in all devices then pass `return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width/4, collectionView.frame.size.width/4);` so in all devices as per your collectionview width it will decrease and increase your cell height and width. if you want to show some specific height and width in specific device then you have to check device if its 5s,6 or ipad and specify height as per your need.